# Rearrange the output of a dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code:

```
dic = {'key1': [0, 0, 0], 'key2': [1, 1, 1], 'key3': [2, 2, 2]}

keys = dic.keys()
values = dic.values()

for i in range(0, len(keys)):
    print keys[i]
    for j in range(0, len(values)):
        print values[i][j]
```

The output that it produces is the following:

```
key3
2
2
2
key2
1
1
1
key1
0
0
0
```

What I would like to have is the following output:

```
key3 key2 key1
2    1    0
2    1    0
2    1    0
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all lists of values have the same length and `keys` has the order you want for the headers, this should do it:

```
print '\t'.join(keys)
for row in zip(*[dic[k] for k in keys]):
    print '\t'.join(map(str, row))
```

**Update**

I used the list comprehension to guarantee the ordering, but according to Python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), dict.keys() and dict.values() ordering is guaranteed if the dictionary isn't changed in between. Considering that, the list comprehension above can be removed and the code can be as simple as:

```
print '\t'.join(keys)
for row in zip(*values):
    print '\t'.join(map(str, row))
```

Comment: Nope, since the dictionary is not ordered, this could backfire badly by putting the wrong data for the wrong keys.

Comment: Absolutely wrong. That would be the case if I were doing `zip(*dic.values())`, but I build the list preserving the order in `keys` to avoid that.

Comment: +1 This works and even allows the user to reorder the columns (for example, sort them before printing)

Comment: @PedroWerneck The lists are of the same size; this does the job. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @InbarRose It is **guaranteed** that the order of keys/value/items does **not** change if you do not perform modifications. It is also **guaranteed** that `keys()`/`values()` and `items()` all provide the same order. (see [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)) Hence what Pedro wrote is *correct*, assuming no other thread modifies the dictionary. And it would be correct even with `zip(*dic.values())`.

Answer (score 0):

Oh wait I misunderstood the question, let me edit.

See if you like it:

```
dic = {'key1': [0, 0, 0], 'key2': [1, 1, 1], 'key3': [2, 2, 2]}

keys = dic.keys()
values = dic.values()
spacing = '{:<8}'
print ''.join(map(str, [spacing.format(element) for element in keys]))
for i in range(len(values)):
    print ''.join(map(str, [spacing.format(element) for element in values[i]]))
```

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: yes yes I misunderstood the question! Geez it stayed on 30 seconds!

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange your loops to look like this:

```
for i in range(len(keys)):
    print keys[i],
print
for line in range(len(values)):
    for column in range(len(keys)):
        print values[column][line], '  ',#change the number of spaces to get the right fit
    print
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use string.join, the docs of which can be found here [string docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html). So, you can print out all of your keys using this line:

```
print " ".join(keys)
```

This will output `key3 key2 key1`

You can do the same thing for your values lists. However, you might want to change the values list into all string with this line:

```
values[:] = [[str(x) for x in y] for y in values]
```

Then, since they're all string, you can perform the string.join() on them.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
dic = {'key1': [0, 0, 0], 'key2': [1, 1, 1], 'key3': [2, 2, 22222]}

def printTable (tbl, borderHorizontal = '-', borderVertical = '|', borderCross = '+'):
    cols = [list(x) for x in zip(*tbl)]
    lengths = [max(map(len, map(str, col))) for col in cols]
    f = borderVertical + borderVertical.join(' {:>%d} ' % l for l in lengths) + borderVertical
    s = borderCross + borderCross.join(borderHorizontal * (l+2) for l in lengths) + borderCross

    print(s)
    for row in tbl:
        print(f.format(*row))
        print(s)

sorted_keys=sorted(dic.keys(),reverse=True)
table=[sorted_keys]
for row in zip(*[dic[k] for k in sorted_keys]):
    table.append(list(row))

printTable(table)
```

Prints

```
+-------+------+------+
|  key3 | key2 | key1 |
+-------+------+------+
|     2 |    1 |    0 |
+-------+------+------+
|     2 |    1 |    0 |
+-------+------+------+
| 22222 |    1 |    0 |
+-------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This does it.

```
dic = {'key1': [0, 0, 0], 'key2': [1, 1, 1], 'key3': [2, 2, 2]}

keys = sorted(dic.keys(), reverse=True)
values = [map(str, dic[k]) for k in keys]

print '\t'.join(keys)
print '\n'.join(['\t'.join(v) for v in zip(*values)])
```

Output:

```
>>> 
key3    key2    key1
2       1       0
2       1       0
2       1       0
```